# load video with multiple resolution android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play a video from raw folder, but the problem is that i have multiple resolution for it and i don't know how to choose the best one. Also i want to handle the problem which appears when the video is not fitted to the screen and i want it be shown on entire width and cut from top and bottom.

This is my current implementation but the video is not fitted to the screen. I also don't want it to be stretched.

```
private void playIntro() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + Utils.getContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + R.raw.video3);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    this.finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

And the xml file

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/intro_video"/>
```

Comment: Take the relative layout and add the property android:centerinparent="True" in videoview..hope it works.

Comment: @rerashhh did you find any solution?